# How can I mock a Non-DB-Model and let it return a given list on call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking

I have a `CommentList` class with a static method `fetch`. The problem is, that it is not an ActiveRecord Model, but it makes http calls to fetch data.

```
class CommentList
  def self.fetch
    # http-foo here
    return ['some', 'data']
  end
end
```

Now I want an other model to use this fetch method and mock away the `CommentList#fetch` method to return a given dataset in my specs.

I only could find mocking gems that play together with a DB.

Am I totally overlooking something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using rspec, it should be easy to do it something like this:

```
CommentList.stub(:fetch => ['some', 'data'])
```

or to make it more of an expectation:

```
CommentList.should_receive(:fetch).and_return(['some', 'data'])
```

Another more elaborate solution would be to set up VCR. Basically what it does in this situation is the first time you run the test, CommentList would really hit the external http service and get back data. VCR then saves that response and from then on, it returns the cached response.

The good thing is that if you ever want to retest the external API call (maybe their API changed?), you just delete the VCR saved data, run your tests, and your tests will again run against the external service and cache fresh data.

Comment: awesome, the #stub method is exactly what I searched for. No idea why I didn't find it. The VCR idea sounds interesting. Will look it up